# Javascript: How to check SHA of fetched script before executing

Tags: javascript, sha, dom

To save money and/or reduce system complexity, I am hosting a script on a server that I don't fully trust. My trust issue might be with the server itself, or the PKI setup on it. The reason doesn't matter exactly, because we can just check a SHA of the script before executing it.

I am currently using the following [standard function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/950098/5896591) to fetch the script:

```
function includeJs(jsFilePath) {
    let js = document.createElement("script");
    js.src = jsFilePath;
    document.body.appendChild(js);
}
```

How do I modify this function so that it accepts a SHA argument, and the script is only executed if its SHA matches the argument value?

*Ideally* we should not modify the server. If we have to play with MIME types or use a WebSocket, that would be acceptable if you believe it is necessary (any insights into *why* such things are necessary would be helpful as well).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subresource_Integrity

Comment: @Joseph Yes, SRI is what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subresource_Integrity

```
function includeJs(jsFilePath, sha) {
    let js       = document.createElement("script");
    js.src       = jsFilePath;
    js.integrity = `sha256-$(sha)`;
    document.body.appendChild(js);
}
```

The sha value is base64, for example generated as follows:

```
openssl dgst -binary -sha256 script.js | openssl base64 -A
```